# FizzzBuzz Python Work Through

Tags: python

Count up from 1. If the number is a multiple of 7 they say "zap" instead of the number. If the number has a digit of 3 in it they say "buzz" instead of the number, and if both things are true they say "zap buzz".

Devise a function zap_buzz that plays a turn of the game. Given a positive integer parameter it should either return that integer value if neither of the "zap"/"buzz" conditions hold. If some condition holds, it should return the string "zap", the string "buzz", or the string "zap buzz", whichever is appropriate. You are allowed to assume the parameter is less than 1000. As in the earlier exercises, please don't convert the integer to a string to determine its digits.

```
>>> zap_buzz(8)
8
>>> zap_buzz(14)
'zap'
>>> zap_buzz(13)
'buzz'
>>> zap_buzz(35)
'zap buzz'
```

---

^^^^^ is the prompt. I have gotten so far:

```
def zapbuzz(x):
        x =0
 if x % 3 == 0 and x % 7 == 0:
     return str("ZapBuzz")
 elif x % == 3 and x % 7 != 0 :
     return str("Zap")
 elif x % 3 != 0 and x % 7 == 0:
     return str("Buzz")
 else /* x % 3 >= 1 or x % 7 >= 1:
     return x
```

****Please don't give me the answer, but a few good tips or maybe a "try thinking about XYZ/etc/whatevertip in a different way would be super awesome. Thank you!

okay I read through the comments, thank you for inspo!
I made the following changes:

```
n = input()
def ZapBuzz(n):
     if n%7 == 0 & n%3 == 0:
         return ("ZapBuzz")
     elif n%7 == 0 & n%3 != 0:
         return ("Zap")
     elif n%7 != 0 & n%3 == 0:
         return ("Buzz")
     else:
         return (n)
```

okay, just talked to a tutor.... I worked out the function, except the issue im having now is that when i input 1 into the function, the terminal spits out 'none'.

```
def zap_buzz(x):
     i = 0
     t = False 
     while i < 3:
         if ((x // 10**i)%10) == 3:
             t = True
         i += 1 
     if t == True and x % 7 == 0:
         return "zap buzz"
     if x % 7 == 0:
         return "zap"
     if t == True:
         return "buzz"
```

Comment: Note that "*[... ] the number has a digit of 3 in it [...]*" is not the same as the number being divisible by 3.

Comment: `return` wont print the string just send the value back, so you can either change `return` to `print` or call your `function` like this `print(zapbuzz(8))`

Comment: @WhatsThePoint The function isn't asked to print anything.

Comment: @ScottHunter for the expected output a `print` would be needed

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Only if "say" == "print".

Comment: Updated code does not address @RobbyCornelissen's point.